# Xcode 9 clipping navigation item display

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

Xcode 9 seems to be clipping the header image to my app for which I have intentional slight overlap of a title PNG (with transparency) over the view below. The currently published App Store version of my app works fine (compiled using Xcode 8), and when that version (and even older versions) of the app are loaded in Xcode 9, clipping occurs. It doesn't occur on the initial view - it happens to any view opened after the initial view (including when users navigate back to the initial view) - see the image posted. I have tried Editor -> Arrange -> Send to Front (not available, as there are not multiple layers in the nav item), View.bringSubview(toFront: self.view), and exhausted all searching for "Xcode navigation item under view" and similar searches. Moreover, storyboard shows the proper overlay of this image over the view, so I'm not sure what is happening to cause the clipping. I have verified that this clipping is not just in the simulator, but on my phone as well. Any help would be appreciated, as I enjoy the slight overlay of the PNG on the view below, and would rather not move the PNG or decrease its size.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/N30Hb.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFSZH.jpg

Thanks in advance for any assistance with getting this working again.

Comment: For now, I have uninstalled Xcode 9 and reverted to Xcode 8.3.3, where rendering is correct. Hopefully in the coming weeks someone can answer why this is happening in Xcode 9!

Comment: Any idea what is the cause of the problem?